# How to join field values in Views in Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: sql, view, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to create a View for exporting some Product Data. Ideally I need to merge two fields values (maybe others if possible).

I know SQL in AX is not really proper SQL as I've tried:

```
Select field1 + field2 from table
```

Which should work and it doesn't

I have a feeling I could this with a method in the View, but I've never done this before and I can't find any decent examples anywhere.

Is what I want to do even possible, and if so how would I do it?

**Edit**

The reason I'm doing this is because I've started using Magento. Its not properly integrated with AX so I was going to create a view with all the data about a product and then do a manual import into Magento.

I want to combine the the SKU of the product with the color id or size id.

So PP1234 and BLU would become PP1234-BLU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking around through the little amount of Documentation there is about Dynamics AX I don't think this can be done.

Seems strange the little amount of SQL you can do.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
 select CAST(field1 AS varchar(number_characters)) 
 + CAST(field2 AS varchar(number_characters))
 from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a staging table, which you would be able to use for export, if it suits your purpose...

```
static void Test(Args _args)
{
    InventTable inventTable;
    StagingTable stagingTable;
    ;

    ttsbegin;

    insert_recordset stagingTable (ItemId, Field1, Field2)
        select ItemId, SourceField1, SourceField2 from inventTable;

    update_recordset stagingTable
        setting Field1 = stagingTable.Field1 + inventTable.SourceField2,
                Field2 = -stagingTable.Field2 + inventTable.SourceField1
    join inventTable
        where inventTable.ItemId == stagingTable.ItemId;

    ttscommit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention why you want to add those two fields together, but if it is merely for presentation, then this can easily be solved by using a display method on the table instance.

```
public Amount myCustomMethod()
{
    return this.fieldA + thisfieldB;
}
```

Since you're using X++, and you're doing exporting, I don't understand why you can't do the calculation as a part of the export.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my question with a better explanation of what I'm trying to do. Thanks.